# Flink Elasticsearch connector for Elasticsearch 8.1+

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am upgrading our flink 1.8 to 1.17, however there were a lot of deprecated methods. I am using Elasticsearch7SinkBuilder for my sink. But it is throwing an error

```
`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response body for Response{requestLine=POST /_bulk?timeout=1m HTTP/1.1, host=http://localhost:9200, response=HTTP/1.1 200 OK}`
```

- Elasticsearch 8.1.1
- Flink 1.17
- Elasticsearch connector 7x

I couldn't find a flink elasticsearch connector for 8.x.
I tried downgrading my local elasticsearch to 7.17 and it works without issue. However the requirement is to use 8.1.1 elasticsearch. Where can I find the connector for 8.1x?

If there is no connector available yet to support ES 8x++, what is the best way to connect to ES in flink? ElasticSearchSinkFunction is also deprecated though.

Answer (score 1):

There currently is no Flink-Elasticsearch 8.x compatible connector. That's because the existing Elasticsearch connector uses the Elasticsearch High Level REST Client, which has been deprecated. Newer versions of that High Level REST Client can't be used, because the license change is incompatible with the Apache license.

Therefore, the Flink-Elasticsearch connector needs to be rewritten to use the Elasticsearch Java Client API. This depends on a contributor who's willing to make this change. The effort can be tracked under https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-26088